Resource Hacker - Modify Icon Says Invalid Command?
I'm trying to use:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Resource Hacker\ResourceHacker" -modify "C:\MyProjectDir\x64\Release\MyAppName.exe", "C:\MyProjectDir\x64\Release\MyAppName.exe", "C:\MyProjectDir\MyAppName\myicon.ico", ICONGROUP, MAINICON, 0

and all I get is:
Error: invalid command
Failed!

I've tried with no 0 after the last comma as well, no difference.  What am I doing wrong?
TIA!!

The command line used is for older versions of Resource Hacker, for the latest versions use:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Resource Hacker\ResourceHacker.exe" -open "C:\MyProjectDir\x64\Release\MyAppName.exe" -save "C:\MyProjectDir\x64\Release\MyAppName.exe" -action modify -res "C:\MyProjectDir\MyAppName\myicon.ico" -mask ICONGROUP,MAINICON,

